# Can I change the cursor and/or background color of my JQGrid while "Loading" message is present?

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

When my jqgrid is "Loading" (initially, after a column sort, or when the user clicks the refresh button) can I change the cursor or the background color of the grid? The user can see the "Loading" message, but sometimes the message is too far down the grid to be very visible.

Thanks for your help. I am fully willing to read up on this if you point me to the correct resources.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the option

```js
loadui: "block"
```

which will show the overlay having classes `"ui-widget-overlay"` and `"jqgrid-overlay"` over the *whole* grid. It will display the overlay additionally to the text "Loading..." (the text are defined in `$.jgrid.defaults.loadtext`). The background of the overlay are defined in jQuery UI style which you use. So the users will clearly see the notification about the loading and all controls of the grid will be blocked during the loading. If you want to customize the background of the overlay you can do this in the [Themeroller](http://jqueryui.com/themeroller) (see the part "Screen for Overlays").

I recommend you additionally to read [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8778241/315935) which shows how to change the position of the "Loading..." text to the *visible* part of the screen.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. Just override the style:

```
.ui-jqgrid .loading { cursor: wait; }
```

Comment: I added this to my code, but it did not work. Is there a specific file I have to go into and overwrite the existing code?