# JQGrid : Delay in "dataurl" need to be notified

Tags: jqgrid

I have a JQGrid with one of cells as a "select" edit type. Data in this cell comes from "dataurl".

While adding a new row/editing an existing row, retrieval of data for "select" cell takes around 40 to 50 seconds. The delay is not an issue but during that time I need to show a Loading message on the Grid or into the "select" cell.

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 1):

One can use [ajaxSelectOptions](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:options) option to customize [jQuery.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) request used to get data from `dataUrl`. For example you can use `beforeSend` callback to do some actions before Ajax request, you can add `error` callback, set `timeout` option which specify the timeout of Ajax request in milliseconds and so on.

To show the "Loading..." message on the grid you need just show the div optionally with overlay. [The answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2706447/315935)) and [another one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8778241/315935) describes in details how it can be done.